# Flutter debugger not working

Tags: android, android-studio

My android studio debugger used to work earlier. But now I realized that it is not working also the instant reload option is now unavailable.

Tools used: Flutter, Android Studio, dart.

Debugger works with my Java projects on same machine.
Debugger just does not specifically work for flutter projects.

I have reinstalled both android studio and flutter. Still the problem persists.

I pulled the same flutter code in other machine and debugger works in that machine.

How to resolve the issue?